# Need help in random forest time series forecast

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, random-forest

I am a beginner in time series forecasting using ML, and I am encountering a strange phenomenon. I have air quality data, in which I have information of various pollutants. The goal is to predict **AIR QUALITY INDEX**.

There are about **10 pollutants** and various weather features. The AQI feature(ground truth) has been created from the dataset itself(ignore why this is so), but note that two features, **PM10 and PM2.5** are highly correlated to target AQI once it is created(**0.8 & 0.81** respectively).Also note that this means that AQI at time(t) is being created from pollutant & weather information at time(t). For 1 step forecasting, I have shifted AQI column 1 step vertically - so now it becomes a problem where ML model must learn to predict 1 day future AQI using data available at time t.

I used random forest for forecasting. Also note that I created additional features such as lag of AQI by 1 day, 2 day ,rolling 30 day and 7 day average. I have not used rolling mean or standard deviation of PM2.5 & PM10.

The strange phenomenon: The forecasts are lagging.

[image]

I know this maybe due to the underlying process being random walk , but I highly doubt so. The actual AQI for 6 years look like that. Any ideas why this might be happening?